# Spring rest - custom header validation on method level

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on spring based rest service and looking for the wy to validate custom request header for some methods and not the others. 
Could You advice what is the best way to achieve this please? Is it possible to achieve it e.g. via custom annotations?:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@validateHeader(name=headerName)  <--??
public DTO method() {
        ...
        return DTO;
}
```

Comment: What does header validation mean?

Comment: Do you mean authorization? If so, I'd recommend spring security.

Comment: I mean request headers like e.g. 'Auth-Token'. This is not part of authorization process. Lets say I would like to make sure that e.g. it exists and is not null before  some specified methods (Not before all of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are asking. If you're looking for your handler method to only handle requests that contain a specific header, you can use the [`@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) for that as well.

`RequestMapping` has a [`headers`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers%28%29) attribute where you can specify

> The headers of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.

Using it like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"my-header"})
```

You can also specify that each header have a specific value (from the javadoc)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", headers = "content-type=text")
```

The javadoc is very descriptive, you can also specify if you want your handler to handle requests that don't contain a specific header. Go through the javadoc.

Comment: Is it possible to return custom Runtime exception from above method call to let user know that particular header is missing ?

Comment: @ppacxnet Not with this solution. Consider looking into how `RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver` works and writing and registering your own.